# Validating associated objects before object.save, or rolling back object.save on associated object vaidation failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Right down to business....

**There are tasks, which have assigned users**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :task_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :assigned_users, :through => :task_assignments, :source => :user

  validates_associated :task_assignments
end
```

**And users have assigned tasks**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :task_assignments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :assigned_tasks, :through => :task_assignments, :source => :task
end
```

**The task_assignments table looks like this**

```
class TaskAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :user, :message => 'You must add some USERS fool!'  
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
end
```

Those associations seem to be working well :0)

Here's the rub - when I add a new task through /tasks/new, I also want to specify a list of users assigned to that task, which the form is returning in "params[:users_list][:id]".

I can get this to work, but I don't want the form to validate unless there is at least one user selected.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this validation to take place in the models rather than in the *create method*.

As you can see, I've thrown "validates _associated :task _assignments" in the tasks method, but to no avail. I'm clearly in over my head.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to name the parameter user_ids...

f.e.:

```
params[:users_ids][:id]
```